# Where was Alfred Pennyworth following the events of No Man's Land?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

I've been reading the "[New Gotham](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman:_New_Gotham_Vol._2_(Collected))" stories that follow up after [No Man's Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3A_No_Man%27s_Land), and I noticed that Alfred is nowhere to be seen. He was present during the events of NML, and could be seen helping Batman on several occasions from various mini batcaves. I think he last appears about 2/3 of the way through NML, but no mention was made of him leaving or quitting... he just seemingly disappears.

A few months after NML, Bruce has the following interaction with his new bodyguard, Sasha Bordeaux ([*ref*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_755)):

[image: Sasha Bordeaux is helping Bruce Wayne tying a bow tie. She's thinking: "Only reason I'm STILL around is that Lucius Fox, the company C.E.O., didn't give Wayne a CHOICE. Four months and I STILL can't figure this guy OUT...". She also tells him: "Can't believe you don't know how to do this yourself", to which Bruce replies that "Alfred used to do this for me".]

So this leads to the question of what happenened to Alfred... **why is Alfred no longer around following the events of No Man's Land and Gotham's rebuilding?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shortly after the events of "Batman: No Man's Land", Alfred spent a semester with Robin (Tim Drake) at **[Brentwood Academy](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Brentwood_Academy)** -- a boarding school in the Bristol Township area, across the river from Gotham City -- beginning in *[Robin Vol. 2 #74](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Robin_Vol_2_74)* (March, 2000).

> ALI BEN KHADIR: This is Tim Drake, Zugir: he will be staying with me.
>
> ZUGIR: Mm.
>
> ALI BEN KHADIR: Zugir stays in the servants quarters in Blandings Hall. Where *your* servant is roomed.
>
> TIM DRAKE: My servant?
>
> ALFRED PENNYWORTH: Oh sir, allow me to hang those things for you. One must look serious for one's first day of classes.
>
> TIM DRAKE: Alfred?
>
> ALFRED PENNYWORTH: And who else but **your personal valet for the remainder of the semester, Master Timothy.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Robin Vol. 2 #74* (March, 2000)</sub>

Alfred subsequently returned to Gotham in *[Detective Comics Vol. 1 #766](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_766)* (March, 2002), when he learned that Bruce Wayne had been charged with the murder of [Vesper Fairchild](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Vesper_Fairchild_(New_Earth)).

From the DC Wiki:

> The news about Vesper's murder has reached the media and at that moment at **Brentwood Academy, where Alfred Pennyworth has been staying with Tim Drake,** Wayne's butler packs his belongings and heads back to Wayne Manor to offer his help in any way he can.

Comment: Awesome - I knew someone on here would know. Thanks!